# add blurred background in an UIImage for making it Squared

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimage

I know how to crop an UIImage or Resize it but I don't know how am gonna do this please see the image :

**Original Image:**

[image: this is the original non-squared image]

**Image I Want:**

[image]

I want to make the original image like this see an background is added to the original  image , now the new image is square in shape.

Any hint or clue how am gonna dos this will be much appreciated.

Comment: i suggest to use two image view one is a blur that the covers background with blur effect or UIVisualEffectView  and one is center that show actual clean image

Comment: @NitinGohel yeah let me try this , thanks man

Answer (score 2):

Look at this documentation. I think it a good start.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBlurEffect_Ref/index.html

My guess his to make 2 transparent (play with the alpha setting) View where you will add something like.

```
var blur:UIBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
var effectView:UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView (effect: blur)
effectView.frame = frame
addSubview(effectView)
```

Comment: you mean to add 2 UIViews at the top and bottom of the image for making it blurred ??

Comment: I was thinking of 2 UIImageView but yep. I'm not sure about your real need ;)

Comment: my goal is to make an image squared , by adding the blurred effect as in the image above